# Why use RANLIB=echo in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I generally have `RANLIB=ranlib` in a makefile, but I came across makefiles with `RANLIB=echo` or `RANLIB=@echo` or `RANLIB=echo >/dev/null`. I am looking for an explanation for such usages.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=569597),

> On most modern Unix systems, applying 'ranlib' to static libraries is completely unnecessary